# UILabel Hebrew character changing in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, hebrew

I have some text in hebrew langaugae when I inserted that text in Plist and read that text shows on label a chacter changes to other which is changing the meaning as per.I have have done research on that. I am adding screen shot for both inputs and outputs, please help me out.
Whether it is iOS sdk issue or any other ? Please explain .Any help would be appriciated.

Using - Xcode 4.6.1 Build number Version 4.6.1 (4H512) and Xcode 5.0 Version 5.0 (5A1413)

Actual text :-

[image]

Out Result :-

[image]

Now we can see red mark charcher changed in out put text with having "plus" sign in output result.

**Already used** :- I have used UTF8 encoding for one character is removed but for the other is not.Please see attached image.Is Sdk related to Xcode or sdk issue? Code that have used.

```
const char   *test = [[[[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"MiddleText"] valueForKey:@"Hebrew"] UTF8String];
[subTitleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:test]];
subTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Bold" size:30];
[subTitleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

[image]

Comment: most likely you are not saving your text as UTF8. Show us the code where you save and get text from plist file.

Comment: My guess it that it's some artifact of the text field you're displaying it in.

Comment: @Sam Budda , I am reading from plist and directly setting to lebel.

Comment: @HotLicks, I am using UIlabel.

Comment: Why do you convert your NSString to `char*` and back to NSString??  Isn't `valueForKey:@"Hebrew"` giving you an NSString?

Comment: And perhaps you should set the font before you do setText.

Comment: I tried setting font before set text but still the same issue and if i am converting the utf then output is same as second image :(

Comment: Converting to UTF8 `char*` and back to NSString* as you are doing is a lossless (though wasteful) transformation.  If the data is corrupted, it's corrupted in `self.dataDic`.

Comment: @HotLicks directly we can not assign const char to UIlabel text that why i am changing back again in NSString.if any other way please tell me .,

Comment: Why did you convert from NSString in the first place??  Unless I'm mistaken (which I never am), `[[[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"MiddleText"] valueForKey:@"Hebrew"]` is an NSString, until you apply the UTF8String method.  There's no need to convert it at all.

Comment: @HotLicks, you saying, In first line, without convert i should use to label?

Comment: Yes.  `UTF8String` converts an NSString to UTF8 in a `const char*`.  You don't need that, since you want an NSString.  (What you *do* need is to understand what you're doing a bit better.)